# Store result of sp_blitzindex in Database

Tags: sp-blitzindex

I#ve some trouble with sp_blitzindex and @outputdatabase.

My Setup:
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU2) (KB4340355) - 13.0.5153.0 (X64) 
    Jun 28 2018 17:24:28 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3  (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

sp_BlitzIndex(TM) v7.6 - July 02, 2019

I would like to store the results in table, running following parameters

```
exec sp_blitzindex 
    @databasename =  @dbName,
    @OutputDatabaseName = 'DBATool',
    @OutputSchemaName = 'dbo',
    @OutputTableName = 'Blitz_index'
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 4):

Make sure to read the documentation and the top of the script, which both note:

```
 - The @OutputDatabaseName parameters are not functional yet. To check the
   status of this enhancement request, visit:
   [https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/issues/221][1]
```